# Word Counter In python

Tags: python

I have tried to create a word counter in python, but my code fails to run.

```
word = input("Enter word or sentence")
input("Your word/ sentence has"+ len(word) + " letters")
```

Could you please help me fix the problem?

The current result is

```
TypeError: Can't convert "int" object into str implicity
```

Comment: `str(len(word))`. Because `len(word)` returns a *number* and it's an `int` object. And you're doing `str_object + int_object`, and Python doesn't understand what do you really want to do. So you have to convert the `int_object` (which returned by `len(word)`) to a `str` object use `str()` function.

Comment: Thank you! It did work when I typed input(len(word))

Comment: And do you want just print out the result, rather than use another `input()`? If so, you should use `print("Your word/ sentence has"+ str(len(word)) + " letters")` instead of an `input()` function.

Comment: I prefer not to use print, becuase the program shuts as soon as it answers the question. Im running it in a cmd.exe style program.

Comment: In the program, if I use input(), then I can summon each line in my time. when I am using print() it prints the message and attempts to close the program.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below code:

```
word = input("Enter word or sentence")
input("Your word/ sentence has"+ str(len(word)) + " letters")
```

Here, I'm using `str(len(word))` instead of just `len(word)`. Because `len(word)` returns a *number* and it's an `int` object.

And you're doing `str_object + int_object`, and Python doesn't understand what do you really want to do.

Let's see:

```
>>> len('foobar')
6
>>> type(len('foobar'))
<class 'int'>
>>> len('foobar') + 'foobar'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
>>>
```

So you have to convert the `int_object` (which returned by `len(word)`) to a `str` object use [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) function.

For example:

```
>>> str(len('foobar'))
'6'
>>> type(str(len('foobar')))
<class 'str'>
>>> str(len('foobar')) + 'foobar'
'6foobar'
```

You can also use [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) instead of two `+`. Which can auto convert all objects to `str`, also it's more readable than your code.

So just use:

```
word = input("Enter word or sentence")
input("Your word/ sentence has {} letters".format(len(word)))
```

Comment: Except they should be using `print` to print, rather than `input`.

Comment: @khelwood: Oh yeah. I don't know why is OP using `input()` here, however that's not the question, I'd post a comment instead of edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error:

```
word = input("Enter word or sentence")
print("Your word/ sentence has"+ str(len(word)) + " letters")
```

Or:

```
word = input("Enter word or sentence")
print("Your word/ sentence has", len(word), " letters")
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` takes a string input. If you wish to print, you must use `print`. `len` returns an integer value. `Str` converts it to string.

```
word = input("Enter word or sentence")
print("Your word/ sentence has"+ str(len(word)) + " letters")
```